# Show that every stable matrix is similar to a contraction

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the square matrix $A$ is stable, i.e., $\rho(A) < 1$. Show that $A$ is similar to a contraction, i.e., show that there exists an invertible matrix $M$ and a matrix $\theta$ such that $A = M\theta M^{-1}$ and $\|\theta\| < 1$, where $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the spectral norm.

In the case where $A$ is diagonalizable, it seems to me that we can just take $M$ and $\theta$ to be the matrices appearing in the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$. But what is $A$ if not diagonalizable?

Comment: The set of diagonalizable matrices is dense.

Comment: The phrasing of this problem makes it sound like you have been told it is true - could you say more about where the question originates? (It is a special case of a more general result about Cstar algebras, but that is overkill in the present case.)

Comment: This is a well-known fact in control theory, where it is often used to prove the asymptotic stability of linear dynamical systems. In particular, if $A$ is stable, then the system $x_{t+1} = Ax_t$ has a global attractor at $x = 0$; this is an easy consequence of the theorem I am asking about.

Answer (score 1):

As you already observed, it suffices to discuss a single Jordan block (of size $k$, say)
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & \ldots &\ldots\\ 0&\lambda& 1&0&\ldots\\ \vdots &&\ddots&\ddots& \vdots\\
\end{bmatrix} \equiv \lambda+N .
$$
Now if $M=\textrm{diag}(m_1,\ldots , m_k)$, then $MNM^{-1}$ has the same shape as $N$, but now with non-zero entries $m_1/m_2, m_2/m_3, \ldots, m_{k-1}/m_k$. So we only need to keep these quotients small.